# Numpy matrix multiplication fails ("shapes not aligned") when second element is a vector/array

Tags: python, numpy

When I multiply a NxN numpy matrix by a N elements numpy array I get an error saying that the shapes are not aligned.

```
from numpy import matrix,ones,eye
A = matrix(eye(3))
b = ones(3)
A*b

ValueError: shapes (3,3) and (1,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Also trasposing the vector does not solve the issue.

```
A*b.T

ValueError: shapes (3,3) and (1,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

This make sense as numpy does not distinguish between column and row vectors so b.T is equal to b.

How can I perform a simple matrix-vector multiplication?

Comment: Have you tried b*A?

Comment: No, but mathematically A* b != b* A !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Don't use `np.matrix`, it's [deprecated](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html). Instead just use 2D arrays for linear algebra.)

Use the matrix multiplication operator `@`:

```
In [177]: from numpy import ones,eye
     ...: A = eye(3)
     ...: b = ones(3)
     ...: A @ b
Out[177]: array([1., 1., 1.])
```

Comment: In the example you provide A* b is the element-wise multiplication. In my original code A* b is the dot product. The equivalent with arrays would be A.dot(b). This however becomes messy when you have multiple dot product (as I do). A 4 matrix dot product would be A.dot(B.dot(C.dot(b))). Agains A* B* C* b using np.matrix

Comment: Ah yes of course, sorry for the distraction. Edited the answer.

Comment: OH MY GOD! Is the @ operator new?! I thought the only way to perform dot product was np.array.dot or np.dot which are both terribly ugly! (must have read it on a book that these where the only two alternatives)

Comment: Yep, only a couple years old! PEP 465, it was added to Python with version 3.5

Comment: You also need to import `array` from `numpy` if you want to make your own factors, not just `eye` or `ones`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from the fact that the operator '*' is performing element-wise multiplication and NOT matrix multiplication as you intend. In python 3 this can be done using the '@' operator, as suggested by w-m. In python 2, however, you must use.

```
import numpy as np
result = np.dot(A,b)
```

The '*' operator will try to multiple every element of A with the corresponding element of b. If these are not the same shape you will get an error, which is what you see.

EDIT: I misunderstood OP's question. '*' will work for matrix multiplication if *both objects are matrices*. However, np.ones(3) produces a numpy array, which is not a numpy matrix object, so it doesn't work and tries to do element-wise multiplication.

if b becomes:

```
b = np.matrix((1,1,1)).T
```

then the code will work. It should also be noted that np.dot(A,b) will work even if both A and b are matrix objects, numpy arrays, or a mix of the two, making it the most general solution.

Comment: This is true for NP.ARRAY. Here we are talking about NP.MATRIX for which * performs MATRIX MULTIPLICATION.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood and have amended my answer with the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because `A` is a matrix, Python calls `A`'s `__mul__` method to compute `A*b`, with `b` as its argument.  That is, it calls `A.__mul__(b)`.  A numpy `matrix` insists on making everything a 2-d matrix, so it converts `b` to a `matrix` before performing the matrix multiplication.  When `b` is converted to a numpy matrix, the result has shape `(1, 3)`:

```
In [248]: b
Out[248]: array([1., 1., 1.])

In [249]: np.matrix(b).shape
Out[249]: (1, 3)
```

Then `__mul__` complains that the shapes are not aligned, because `A` has shape `(3, 3)` and the converted `b` has shape `(1, 3)`.

One way to fix this is to ensure that `b` is 2-d with shape `(3, 1)` before doing the multiplication:

```
In [250]: b = ones((3, 1))

In [251]: A * b
Out[251]: 
matrix([[1.],
        [1.],
        [1.]])
```

In the long term, though, it would be better to modify your code to not use `matrix` at all, as mentioned by @w-m.